# Can javax.mail.Session.setDebug() to true slow the application down?

Tags: jakarta-mail

We would like to know how our application is sending email by setting javax.mail.Session.setDebug() to true. It looks like doing this slows the application down. We would like to verify that this is the case. Has anyone ever had experience with running the mail session in the debug mode. Otherwise, we need to find out why our app is underperforming.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously doing the additional work of writing the debug output is going to slow the application down.  How much it slows it down will depend on where the output is being written.